# Styling icon and button when select is disabled

Tags: html, css

I have a select with reset style and trying to create additional button and dropdown arrow icon inside using `::after` selector and `content`. And now I'm trying to style the select in case of `disabled` applied on it. For the button case, I change the style by using `select:disabled + button.resetDropdownButton::after`. However, I still can't find the way to re-style the arrow icon when select is disabled. Anyone know how to do it?

```css
select, option {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

button.resetDropdownButton::after {
    content: "\2716";
}

.filterWrapper {
    /*    flex: 1;*/
    margin: 0 1rem 1rem;
    position: relative;
}

    .filterWrapper label {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: .25rem;
    }

.filterItem {
    position: relative;
}

    .filterItem::after {
        /*add arrow down from fa-icon*/
        content: '\f107';
        font: normal normal normal 12px/1 FontAwesome;
        color: black;
        right: 8px;
        top: -2px;
        height: 26px;
        padding: 15px 0px 0px 8px;
        position: absolute;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .filterItem select {
        width: 100%;
        /*padding: 0.5rem 1rem;*/
        padding-right: 2rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
        padding-top: 0.5rem;
        padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
        font-size: 1rem;
        border-radius: 6px;
        border: 2px solid #CBD2E0;
        transition: .2s all;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

        .filterItem select::-webkit-input-placeholder {
            color: var(--grey);
        }

        .filterItem select:focus {
            outline: none;
            background-color: rgba(214, 238, 247, 0.5);
            border: 1px solid var(--blue);
            box-shadow: 0 0 3px var(--blue);
        }

        .filterItem select > option {
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

.filterWrapper .resetDropdownButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    right: 1.15rem;
    bottom: .5rem;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    /*    font-weight: bold;*/
    border: 0 solid transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}

    .filterWrapper .resetDropdownButton:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

select:disabled + button.resetDropdownButton::after {
    color: gray;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

select:disabled + button.resetDropdownButton:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

select:disabled + filterItem::after {
    /*add arrow down from fa-icon*/
    color: yellow;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="filterWrapper">
  <div class="filterItem">
      <select disabled>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
      </select>
      <button class="resetDropdownButton"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect the arrow icon that I create using `::after` on the div wrapper can be restyle like the button one when select disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Keeping the same HTML structure

This can be achieved with `.filterItem:has(select:disabled)::after`. But selector `:has()` is not well supported so far. You can read [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has).

```css
select,
option {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

button.resetDropdownButton::after {
  content: "\2716";
}

.filterWrapper {
  /*    flex: 1;*/
  margin: 0 1rem 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.filterWrapper label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .25rem;
}

.filterItem {
  position: relative;
}

.filterItem::after {
  /*add arrow down from fa-icon*/
  content: '\f107';
  font: normal normal normal 12px/1 FontAwesome;
  color: black;
  right: 8px;
  top: -2px;
  height: 26px;
  padding: 15px 0px 0px 8px;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.filterItem select {
  width: 100%;
  /*padding: 0.5rem 1rem;*/
  padding-right: 2rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 2px solid #CBD2E0;
  transition: .2s all;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.filterItem select::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: var(--grey);
}

.filterItem select:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: rgba(214, 238, 247, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid var(--blue);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px var(--blue);
}

.filterItem select>option {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.filterWrapper .resetDropdownButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  right: 1.15rem;
  bottom: .5rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  /*    font-weight: bold;*/
  border: 0 solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.filterWrapper .resetDropdownButton:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

select:disabled+button.resetDropdownButton::after {
  color: gray;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

select:disabled+button.resetDropdownButton:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.filterItem:has(select:disabled)::after {
  /*add arrow down from fa-icon*/
  color: gray;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="filterWrapper">
  <div class="filterItem">
    <select disabled>
      <option>A</option>
      <option>B</option>
      <option>C</option>
    </select>
    <button class="resetDropdownButton"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Change HTML structure

You can change the HTML structure and include the arrow inside your `.filterItem` and after the select, while also applying some CSS to make it look good. 
This is better and more supported so far.
Something like this:

```css
select,
option {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

button.resetDropdownButton::after {
  content: "\2716";
}

.filterWrapper {
  /*    flex: 1;*/
  margin: 0 1rem 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.filterWrapper label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .25rem;
}

.filterItem {
  position: relative;
}


.filterItem select {
  width: 100%;
  /*padding: 0.5rem 1rem;*/
  padding-right: 2rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 2px solid #CBD2E0;
  transition: .2s all;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.filterItem select::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: var(--grey);
}

.filterItem select:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: rgba(214, 238, 247, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid var(--blue);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px var(--blue);
}

.filterItem select>option {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.filterWrapper .resetDropdownButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  right: 1.15rem;
  bottom: .5rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  /*    font-weight: bold;*/
  border: 0 solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.filterWrapper .resetDropdownButton:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

select:disabled+button.resetDropdownButton::after {
  color: gray;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

select:disabled+button.resetDropdownButton:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.arrow::after {
  /*add arrow down from fa-icon*/
  content: '\f107';
  font: normal normal normal 12px/1 FontAwesome;
  color: black;
  right: 8px;
  top: -2px;
  height: 26px;
  padding: 15px 0px 0px 8px;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

select:disabled + button.resetDropdownButton + span.arrow::after {
  color: gray;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="filterWrapper">
  <div class="filterItem">
    <select disabled>
      <option>A</option>
      <option>B</option>
      <option>C</option>
    </select>
    <button class="resetDropdownButton"></button>
    <span class="arrow"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The `has` selector kinda interesting, unfortunately it won't be supported on older browser. Kinda agrees with the `span` and styling approach, though I hope don't have to add anything on html.

Comment: @OpayHero Why not though? If your concern is accessibility, you can use aria-hidden or aria-label etc. By the looks of the current HTML structure, there is no other CSS selector (apart from :has()) to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: True, forget I could use that option too. Thanks @GeorgeChond!